# what is bootstrap time?

Tags: spring-data, spring-mongo

I know compile time and runtime. when I read Spring-Data reference, I read this
"If the repository infrastructure does not find a declared query for the method at **bootstrap time**, it fails"

when is bootstrap time?

Answer (score 1):

Most spring projects are bootstrapped - meaning that they are ready for [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/).

Spring-boot's "**Bootstrap time**" refers to when the application is loading all the Auto Configures.

Comment: Was your question answered?